# ios purchase_date time format?

Tags: ios, time

```
      "applicationType" : "User",
        "applicationDSID" : "41111549283",
        "isInstalled" : "1",
        "installType" : "0",
        "originalInstallType" : "0",
        "purchaserDSID" : "41111549283",
        "bundleVersion" : "1",
        "itemID" : 0,
        "storeFront" : 0,
        "isPurchasedReDownload" : 0,
        "sdkVersion" : "10.2",
        "applicationIdentifier" : "com.ppjb.carrier102.gr-bfb7fd10ea6bb7d0e055279b1dd26d6c86a2ce67-1493118182.63",
        "bundleModTime" : "514846100"
```

what is the bundleModTime mean? never see this time format. any idea?

Comment: This is an undocumented field.  From the receipt validation guide - "Keys not documented below are reserved for use by Apple and must be ignored by your app."

Comment: I knowed that. i just want to know how a datetime can be converted to NSInteger just like the one bundleModTime showing.

Comment: You can use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` or `timeIntervalSince1970`

Comment: Check this time interval using [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/) link it gives me today's date for above `bundleModTime` time. About what it means - I have no idea. Need to check document and revert you back

Comment: 514846100 is not a timestamp. how to convert datetime to the number like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test shows that that value is a time interval since reference date:

```
let aDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 514846100)
print(aDate)
print(aDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
```

gives

> 2017-04-25 20:48:20 +0000
>
> 514846100.0

As to what this timestamp *means*, only Apple knows.  They say

> Keys not documented ... are reserved for use by Apple and must be ignored by your app.